# insert JSON values into a MySQL table using python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-requests

I have a JSON file recover from **requests.get**

here is some of my JSON:

```
 [{"order":{"id":"B4589B26","status_order_id":5,"status_order_name":"Sent","customer_id":326
"order_products":[{"order_product":{"id":96218,"order_id":96538,"product_id":59320,}}],"customer_email":"user@gmail.com","customer_company":"SARL","customer_name":"user user", .....
```

here is my code:

```
token = "xxxx"

r = requests.get('url', auth=('user@gmail.com', token))

mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='user',
db='ytm_db')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

data = r.json()
json_obj = json.loads(r)

for ord in json_obj["order"]:
    print("id:", ord["id"])
    print("status_id:", ord["status_order_id"])
    print('---')
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_test (id, status_order_id, customer_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (ord["id"], ord["status_order_id"], ord["customer_id"]))

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print ("Done")
```

I have this error:

```
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right solution :

```
json_obj = r.json()

for ord in json_obj:
    print("id:", ord["order"]["id"])
    print("status_id:", ord["order"]["status_order_id"])
    print('---')
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_test (id, status_order_id, customer_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (ord["order"]["id"], ord["order"]["status_order_id"], ord["order"]["customer_id"]))

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need this line `json_obj = json.loads(r)` . `r.json()` returns you a json response.

**Ex:**

```
json_obj = r.json()

for ord in json_obj["order"]:
    print("id:", ord["id"])
    print("status_id:", ord["status_order_id"])
    print('---')
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_test (id, status_order_id, customer_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (ord["id"], ord["status_order_id"], ord["customer_id"]))

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: I tried with this code but I have this error : 

       ** for ord in json_obj["order"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

@Rakesh you have an idea please?

Comment: Looks like `json_obj ` is a list try iterating it first

Comment: I am a beginner in python I did not understand, can you explain how to do or what to look for, please!